# Run both ASP.NET Web Pages & MVC together

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I will try to explain my situation. I have a website wrote with asp.net web pages 4 years ago. Now, I want to add a new admin panel and I wrote it with mvc.

Let's say my site is **mywebsite.com** and my new admin panel will be like **mywebsite.com/admin/**

I've published it and uploaded to /admin folder. But when i try to open it, it gives me

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

I've tried these solutions:

```
    <system.webServer> 
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" /> 
    </system.webServer>
```

Added this to my web.config, but nothing chages.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Tried this, and nothing changes either.
    `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;`

Tried to add this to my `RouteConfig.cs` file, and nothing changes.
I don't have access to IIS, and my hosting provider says that my hosting supports MVC.
I am stuck. Like for two weeks. Any ideas would really appreciated.

Comment: i don't know if you can run one hosted inside the other.  I would add the MVC as a new Application or website with your hosting provider, and have them add a binding for your route to your new Application, or even just use a new url.